# I'm wearing some else's hat...

Tags: bug, winter-bash

[Hani Gotc](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/89734/hani-gotc)'s hat shows up on my gravatar. At least for me:

[image]

Something's wrong here...

Comment: Did you pull a proof out of his hat?

Comment: @Bill lets see...no. Any idea? BTW: Nice to see you back...